# Show base in fugitive.vim conflict diff

Tags: git, vim, git-merge, vim-fugitive

By default if you use [fugitive.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive)'s `:Gdiff` on a file buffer which is in conflict with git, you will get a [three way diff](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/fugitive-vim-resolving-merge-conflicts-with-vimdiff/) showing `HEAD`, the working copy (with conflict markers), and the `merge`.

I like to have `git config merge.conflictstyle diff3` set, which [includes the base](http://blog.wuwon.id.au/2010/09/painless-merge-conflict-resolution-in.html) (most recent common ancestor of `HEAD` and `merge` in the conflict markers.

Unfortunately even with `diff3` as the `conflictstyle` in fugitive.vim you still only get 3 panes (no base).

Does anyone know how to make show it in another pane? Ideally about the working copy.

[This comment](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/fugitive-vim-resolving-merge-conflicts-with-vimdiff/#comment-200528090) from Tim Pope seems to provide some clue, but I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: Did you try [Threesome](http://sjl.bitbucket.org/threesome.vim/)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with the following steps:

- `:split` - Do a horizontal split
- `:Gdiff` - Diff in the top window
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd> - Move focus to bottom window
- `Gedit :1` - Load ancestor in bottom window

`Gedit :2` loads head and `Gedit :3` loads the merge

Answer (score 5):

The quickest way I know of is this command, issued in the conflicted buffer:

```
:Gsdiff :1 | Gvdiff
```

You must enter these commands as a one-liner, the effect is different when you enter them as two separate commands.

The result looks like this:

```
+---------------------------------------+
|         common ancestor (:1)          |
+-----------+--------------+------------+
|           |              |            |
| HEAD (:2) | working copy | merge (:3) |
|           |              |            |
+-----------+--------------+------------+
```

The stuff inside the brackets are the 'revision' specifiers that fugitive.vim understands in this context. See `:h fugitive-revision` for more information.

Comment: Is it possible to make this a different order? It'd be useful to swap the common and working copies.

Comment: @Holloway: I just added an answer that does exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use git mergetool -t gvimdiff. It will open 4 windows in gvimdiff. It's not built into fugitive, however still you can use vim to do your 3-way merge.

Answer (score 0):

These answers are all great if you just want to open the diff on a file you already have open in a vim buffer. I prefer using `git mergetool` and having that open a 4-way diff view like the following:

```
+-----------+----------------------+------------+
|           |                      |            |
| HEAD (:2) | common ancestor (:1) | merge (:3) |
|           |                      |            |
+-----------+----------------------+------------+
|                 working copy                  |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Thanks to the other answers here, I was able to make that work by creating a file called `diff.vim` and placing it in my `~/.vim` directory:

```
Gsdiff :1
exe 1 . "wincmd w"
Gvdiff!
call feedkeys(winnr()."\<C-W>jgg", 'n')
```

Then, just make your mergetool command execute `vim -f "$MERGED" -S "$HOME/.vim/diff.vim"`. My `~/.gitconfig` has the following:

```
[mergetool "fugitive"]
    cmd = vim -f "$MERGED" -S "$HOME/.vim/diff.vim"
[merge]
    tool = fugitive
```

Hope this is useful to others out there.