# How to display 'word-level' changes when resolving conflicts with 3-way diff?

Tags: vim, vim-fugitive

Resolving conflicts with fugitive is great. After reading 
[Painless Merge Conflict Resolution in Git](http://blog.wuwon.id.au/2010/09/painless-merge-conflict-resolution-in.html), I started to think how to display changes not only on a line-level but also on word-level.

All examples / cases are based on [painless_git_conflicts_resolution repo](https://github.com/ryrych/painless_git_conflicts_resolution). [Hub](https://github.com/github/hub) was used to make `git clone` command more succinct.

### Fugitive with disabled `diff3` conflict style.

`hub clone ryrych/painless_git_conflicts_resolution fugitive_no_diff3
cd fugitive_no_diff3/
git checkout beta
git merge origin/master
vim roses.txt
:Gdiff`

The result is following:

[image: Resolving conflicts with fugitive without diff3 enabled]

Problem is that you can only see that all lines changed in some way. This example is very short, but how many of you spotted that **of** has been added in line 3?

RubyMine can solve that, though not always, leaving you more than often with diff marks, and without diff highlighting. Though on this screen shot there are no diff marks, the lack of 'contrast' makes it very difficult to solve that conflicts.

[image: Resolving conflicts with RubyMine]

### Fugitive with enabled diff3 + displaying common ancestor:

[Show base in fugitive.vim conflict diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682164/show-base-in-fugitive-vim-conflict-diff) stackoverflow question made me try [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22939888/1617108), but the solution wasn't an improvement.

`hub clone ryrych/painless_git_conflicts_resolution fugitive_with_diff3
cd fugitive_with_diff3/
git checkout beta
git merge origin/master
vim roses.txt
:split
:Gdiff
[Ctrl][W][J]
:Gedit :1`

[image: Resolving conflicts with fugitive without diff3 disabled]

### opendiff as a `mergetool`

`hub clone ryrych/painless_git_conflicts_resolution opendiff
cd opendiff/
git checkout beta
git merge origin/master
git mergetool`

and voilà!

[image: Resolving conflicts with opendiff]

This, of course, solves the problem, but makes me rely upon an external tool that was only designed for one system. To sum up: is it possible to achieve something similar in Vim as in opendiff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that on my machine (running vim 7.4) all the diffs do highlight the differences within lines. The text from `:help view-diff` implies that this is standard behavior. It says nothing about turning the feature on or off, only that the `hl-DiffText` highlight group is used for "Changed text inside a Changed line"

I would try a different color scheme, or at least try and double check that your current color scheme defines an appearance for `hl-DiffText`

**EDIT**: Apparently, the given example is actually really bad for showing word-level differences. Every line has changes in multiple places, they're very short, and there's no lines that remain completely unchanged to provide context. As you can see in the screenshots, removing the conflict marker puts all the "all my base" lines at the same line number, and the word-level differences get highlighted. You might want to try with a more complex repo/merge conflict.

[image: :Gdiff in vim not showing word-level changes]

[image: :Gdiff in vim showing word-level changes]

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot?

Comment: @wryrych I've updated the answer. This test repo is actually pretty bad for testing word-level conflicts.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I tried different color schemes but none of them seemed to display the diff as I wanted. In the meantime I found out that git itself allows for enabling word-level diff in terminal output (`git diff --color-words`).

You're right, this example is not a very good one to show diff in action.