# in fugitive.vim show diff between target|merge and common ancestor

Tags: git, vim, vim-fugitive

I am using  fugitive.vim's :Gdiff. 
I would like to get the diff between the head and the common ancestor and between merge and the common ancestor.
I am using instructions from here [Show base in fugitive.vim conflict diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682164/show-base-in-fugitive-vim-conflict-diff), to get the following:

```
+---------------------------------------+
|         common ancestor (:1)          |
+-----------+--------------+------------+
|           |              |            |
| HEAD (:2) | working copy | merge (:3) |
|           |              |            |
+-----------+--------------+------------+
```

However I would like to also see the diff between (:2) and (:1)  and between (:3) and (:1)

Answer (score 1):

The [splice plugin](https://github.com/sjl/splice.vim) aims at *resolving conflicts during three-way merges*. It'll permit to quickly select which buffers shall be compared.

However, it won't show what your are looking for because of a vim limitation: there can be only one diff at a time (even if it involves more than one buffer).

Answer (score 0):

I use this [vim as a git mergetool script](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/A_better_Vimdiff_Git_mergetool).
It diffs the common ancestor with (:2) or (:3), however they are in a different tab.